# c++ JSON serialize using reflection

Tags: c++, json, reflection

Can someone modify given code so my commented code works. Actully I don't understand how reflect macro is working at first place.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define REFLECT(x) template<class R> void reflect(R& r) { r x; }

typedef struct _Employee {
    string emp_id;
    int salary;
    REFLECT(
        ("Emp_id", emp_id)
        ("Salary", salary)
    )
} Employee;

class Demo {
    std::ostream& output;
    bool flag = false;
public:
    Demo(std::ostream& output) : output(output) {}
    template<class T>

    auto write(T& myobj) -> decltype(myobj.reflect(*this), void())
    {
        output << "{";
        flag = false;
        myobj.reflect(*this);
        output << "}\n";
    }
    void write(int val) {
        output << val;
    }
    void write(std::string& val) {
        output << '"' << val << '"';
    }
    template<class T>
    Demo& operator()(const char* emp_id, T& myfield) {
        if (flag) {
            output << ",";
        }
        flag = true;
        output << "\"" << emp_id << "\":";
        write(myfield);
        return *this;
    }
};
int main() {
    Demo myObj(std::cout);
    //Demo myObj();
    Employee emp1 = { "2324354", 90000 };
    myObj.write(emp1);
    //std::cout << myObj.write(emp1);
}
```

I am not good at latest c++ coding styles and standards.

I got this snippet code from internet and want to use for json serializatzion.

Regards.

SM

Comment: All `write` functions return `void`; you cannot pass the result of calling this function to the `<<` operator, since there is no result... Reading `std::cout << myObj.write(emp1);` indicates that this expression is supposed to write 2 things to `std::cout` making this a weird statement one way or the other...

Comment: ok my assumption might be wrong. I just want to store write method result to a string variable. Your comment will be helpfull if you give some suggession to modify first write method of Demo class. Your comment lead me no where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TRT thanks for your explanation. I got following solution.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#define REFLECT(x) template<class R> void reflect(R& r) { r x; }

typedef struct _Employee {
    string emp_id;
    int salary;
    REFLECT(
        ("Emp_id", emp_id)
        ("Salary", salary)
    )
} Employee;

typedef struct _Demo {
    bool flag = false;
    template<class T>
    auto write(T& myobj) -> decltype(myobj.reflect(*this), string()){
        std::stringstream ss;

        //cout << "{";
        output.push_back("{");
        flag = false;
        myobj.reflect(*this);
        //cout << "}\n";
        output.push_back("}\n");

        for (auto& s : output)
        {
            ss << s;
        }
        return ss.str();
    }
    void write(int& n) {
        //cout << n;
        output.push_back(to_string(n));
    }
    void write(string& s) {
        //cout << '"'<<s<<'"';
        output.push_back(string("\"") + s + "\":");
    }
    template<class T>
    struct _Demo& operator()(const char* emp_id, T& myfield) {
        std::stringstream ss;

        if (flag) {
            //cout << ",";
            output.push_back(",");
        }
        flag = true;
        //cout << "\"" << emp_id << "\":";
        output.push_back(string("\"") + emp_id + "\":");
        write(myfield);
        return *this;
    }
private:
    vector<string> output;
} Demo;

int main()
{
    Demo demo;
    Employee emp = { "2324354", 90000 };
    cout << demo.write(emp) << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define REFLECT(x) template<class R> void reflect(R& r) { r x; }

typedef struct _Employee
{
  std::basic_string<char> emp_id;
  int salary;
  template<class R>
  inline void reflect(R & r)
  {
    r("Emp_id", this->emp_id)("Salary", this->salary);
  }
};
```

You use chain call operator() of Demo class. That's all

Comment: what is ```auto write(T& myobj) -> decltype(myobj.reflect(*this), void())```? how to make it to write to a string stream or variable?

Comment: It's a check that myobj.reflect(Demo) exists. If it isn't exists this template function will not generate.

Comment: @SM I don't understand what you want. This function already write to stream. ostringstream will help you

Comment: @TRT, i want this code to work ```Demo myObj();
    Employee emp1 = { "2324354", 90000 };
    std::cout << myObj.write(emp1);```

Comment: @TRT i modified code in question can you check and suggest me changes if possible

Comment: @SM are you sure that reference to local variable would work?

Comment: @SM it's a bad style. Rename this function, now it's not write, maybe json.stringify or i.e but not write)

Comment: @TRT this is example code from internet for testing. I think just missing << operator in demo class.

Comment: @SM you just wanna add operator <<?

Comment: I looked at my other code and got solution with it. thanks for your help.